# Where is the buildResources directory?

Tags: electron

I'm adding an icon to my electron app, but I have no idea where the `buildResources` directory is!
I've looked everywhere, the out folder, the .git folder, but it seems to be nonexistent!

Comment: Also, I realized that electron-builder doesn't support squirrel, how do I add the icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildResources` does not have a default value, so you must set it. You would set it in **package.json**, here's an example.

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My desription.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    //... scripts
  },
  "build": {
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources"
    },
    //... rest of properties
  },
  //... rest of file
}
```

**Your project**

```
app/
dist/
node_modules/
resources/
  icon.ico
  ... other resources
package.json
webpack.config.js
//... other files/folders
```

Comment: "but it seems to be nonexistent!", stack overflow never made me laugh this much XD